# Hyper-V Virtual Switch Error & NIC Bridging

Tags: hyper-v, switch, bridging

I am getting an error when making an External Virtual Switch in Hyper-V. I recently was using NIC bridging in Windows, but deleted that bridge. I feel that it wasn't removed properly which may be causing my issue.

Regardless when creating an External Virtual Switch I get the Error:
Virtual Switch Manager: Error applying Virtual Switch Properties changes.

Comment: I am also noticing that the Ethernet 2 Virtual Adapter isn't listed as Enabled.

Comment: I am noticing the Virtual Switch driver in Device Manager has an exclaimation.

Comment: Fixed it! I uninstalled the faulty driver which removed it and did not rescan it in Device Manager. I then created the virtual switch in Hyper-V. I don't think the bridge removal caused it, but it is good to note that if you are bridging you may need to remove it for creating a v-switch.